# How to send multiple contacts via Gmail?

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-contacts

Is there a way to attach multiple contact information to an email? Manually copying field-by-field to text body is even worse than sending them via SMS.

Comment: Well, ok. The answer is correct, even if far from satisfying. I personally will not force people to deal with vcards - who knows what software and devices they use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the web-based version you can using the export functionality. Select you contacts in the contacts browser, select More->Export and select vCard format for your selected contacts. You can then download the file and attach it to your email.

Comment: True. Still sms beats gmail here :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but was able to find a quick way out on the Mac. I am sure you can do this on other OSes too with a thick Contacts client.

1. I synced my Mac Address Book application with my gmail contacts.
2. Created a new email message
3. Dragged the contacts from the Address Book application into the body of the mail message

I had an email with multiple VCFs attached.